# What is the meaning of "regular pitch" when applied to a propeller?

Tags: propeller, terminology

I am looking at parameters of a propeller that looks like this:

> 3 blade xx inch diameter (regular pitch)

What does "regular pitch" mean?

Comment: Could you show us the propeller you are looking at so we can see this in context?

Comment: This is not a common expression?

Comment: Context is going to be key here. Can you post an example where you've seen this phrase?

Answer (score 3):

Ill assume you are asking the context of fixed pitch propellers. In which case "regular pitch" is either the standard pitch for the airframe in question or some mid range pitch to deliver average performance. [There are usually various propeller options for a given aircraft:](http://www.flightlearnings.com/2009/09/17/fixed-pitch-propellers/)

> There are two types of fixed-pitch propellers: climb and cruise.
>   Whether the airplane has a climb or cruise propeller installed depends
>   upon its intended use. The climb propeller has a lower pitch,
>   therefore less drag. Less drag results in higher rpm and more
>   horsepower capability, which increases performance during takeoffs and
>   climbs, but decreases performance during cruising flight.

[You can read more here.](https://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aircraft-building/building-your-aircraft/while-youre-building/building-articles/propellers-and-spinners/the-fixed-pitch-propeller-dilemma)